# Shadow-box issue

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I have the following container with an image and some text inside. 
Currently this is what i have tried:

```
background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
box-shadow: 20px 20px 45px #00000029;
```

The issue is at the top. I don't want the line at the top to be displayed neither the small line above the image.

I know this is due to the container, but i've been searching for a way but all the ways i've tried they show the top line.
[image: Box Container issue]

[image: container-image]

Comment: The only way to avoid the box shadow bleeding out of the top is to adjust the spread/blur of the box shadow so that the shadow is not visible on the top. It's not possible to selectively crop box-shadow from edges. Alternatively, you can create a dummy pseudo-element that is slightly offset from the top, and declare box-shadow on the pseudo-element instead.

Comment: you were right, i used -15 for spread and it worked. it;s hard a little bit to see the left line but it definitely helped